# application defined or object defined error when creating calculated fields

Tags: vba

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable13").PivotFields("OOS VALUE"), "Sum of OOS VALUE", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable13").PivotFields("Sales"), "Sum of Sales", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").CalculatedFields.Add "OOS", _
    "=OOS VALUE/Sales", True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("OOS").Orientation = _
    xlDataField
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Sum of OOS VALUE")
    .NumberFormat = "?#,##0.00"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Sum of Sales")
    .NumberFormat = "?#,##0.00"
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Sum of OOS")
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
```

I am getting the application defined or object defined error at the part where the calculated field is made. what's wrong? i'm using the record a macro feature if that helps

Comment: Are you sure the exact name of the field is correct, e.g. "OOS VALUE"?

Comment: Try `"='OOS VALUE'/'Sales'"`